# How to get access to hdfs using kerberos service ticket

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, kerberos

I'm using Apache Kerby for generation tgt and then service ticket (sgt) to particular resource hdfs. Then save these both tickets to one file (myTicket).
Then I use UserGroupInformation.getBestUgi(myTicket, user). It works fine but in logs I can see that UserGroupInformation goes to TGS for service ticket despite of the fact that it already got it. I am sure my ticket is right.
How to avoid exta call to TGS? Is it possible using UserGroupInformation or there is other way?

I tried this code

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");
config.set("hadoop.kerberos.ticket.renew", "false");
UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(config);

UserGroupInformation ugi = UserGroupInformation.getBestUgi(myTicket, user);
FileSystem hdfs = ugi.doAs((PrivilegedAction<FileSystem>) () -> {
        try {
             return FileSystem.get(config);  
        } catch (Exception e) {
             throw new RuntimeExeption();
        }
}
```